# Can I define a function pointer pointing to an object of std::function type?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Something like the following:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> func = [](int x){return x;};
    int* Fptr(int) = &func; //error
}
```

The errors I get are

```
temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temp.cpp:6:15: warning: declaration of ‘int* Fptr(int)’ has ‘extern’ and is initialized
  int* Fptr(int) = &func; //error
               ^
temp.cpp:6:20: error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘func’
  int* Fptr(int) = &func; //error
                    ^
temp.cpp:6:20: error: function ‘int* Fptr(int)’ is initialized like a variable
```

A more direct way to go from lambda function to function pointer would be useful to know as well.

Comment: Do you need the std::function or are you just trying to get a function pointer to a (capture-less) lambda?

Comment: No. Function pointers point to functions, not objects that behave like functions.

Comment: @Mat originally I was interested in capture-less lambda. I'm not sure if lambda functions would behave like an rvalue making pointers impossible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
int* Fptr(int)
```

declares a function "Fptr" that takes an `int` and returns `int*`.

A function pointer declaration looks like

```
int (*Fptr)(int)
```

Further,`std::function<int(int)>` is not the type of your lambda function, but your lambda function can be implicitly converted to  that type.

Fortunately, a (non-capturing) lambda function can *also* be implicitly converted to a function pointer, so the most direct way from lambda function to function pointer is

```
int (*Fptr)(int) = [](int x){return x;};
```

Comment: Wow, +1 for the fact that a non-capturing lambda can be treated as a function pointer, nice to know.